# How to start and connect to the newly installed MongoDB server?

Tags: mongodb

I have successfully installed mongodb. As I typed mongodb in one shell and mongo on the next powershell. It worked fine but the arrow sign after mongo isn't being displayed and I am unable to code further. What's the problem and how to fix it. Screenshot has been attached along with.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKFtI.png)

Comment: Did you install the MongoDB Community Server or any other version of it?
Here is the link to MongoDB Community Server
https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.6-signed.msi

Comment: If you have already installed the MongoDB successfully, you must **start** the server _and_ then **connect** to the server. See this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition-from-the-command-interpreter) for details.